# Filter on 3 True/False Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to combine 3 true/false columns in a visual slicer where selecting the column name filters all where that column is true.

I want the user to be able to pick (single-select):
- Column1
- Column2
- Column3

The page should be filtered on all true in column.

My Data

```
Column1| Column2| Column3|
true   | true   | false  |
false  | true   | false  |
false  | false  | true   |
```

The data overlaps so I am unable to create a calculate column using if statements. Im really stuck on this any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to combine Page Level Filters ?

Comment: @Rubens_Z my requirement is that I can create a Slicer with the 3 columns; is there a way I can achieve this with Page Level Filters? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified if you want it in M or DAX.
Solution in M code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCgkKdVXSUXJz9AlG0LE6GBJgLkgcRYB0cfItQOYjm4PqdCw24DCIkMW4bSDfJGL9gMPTxIYRqjGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t, col3 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col1", type logical}, {"col2", type logical}, {"col3", type logical}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "AllTrue_M", each if [col1] = false then false else if [col2] = false then false else if [col3] = false then false else true)
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

Or add calculated column in DAX:

```
CalculatedColumn = IF(
    'Table'[col1]=TRUE() && 'Table'[col2]=TRUE() && 'Table'[col3]=TRUE()
    , "ALL TRUE"
    , "NOT ALL TRUE"
    )
```

Alternatively, check for other combinations:

```
CalculatedColumn = SWITCH(TRUE(), 
'Table'[col1]=TRUE() && 'Table'[col2]=TRUE() && 'Table'[col3]=TRUE(), "ALL TRUE", 
'Table'[col1]=FALSE() && 'Table'[col2]=FALSE() && 'Table'[col3]=FALSE(), "ALL FALSE",
"MIXED")
```

Indeed it is interesting problem how to make check for multiple condition. Sadly `AND` function in DAX accepts only two arguments (conditions). You can check multiple conditions with "&&" operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-operator-reference#logical-operators

Comment: This just says whether all are true or false (or mixed), he wants a slicer where each option is selectable individually.